# How to remove / add public network to a server in Rackspace API

Tags: permissions, cloud, openstack, rackspace, nova-network

I have a server in Rackspace API. I would like to use the `nova` command to remove the public network interface.

I am using the command:

```
nova virtual-interface-list <instance_id>
```

and then

```
nova virtual-interface-delete <instance_id> <virtual_interface_id>
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: Policy doesn't allow compute_extension:virtual_interfaces:delete to be performed. (HTTP 403) (Request-ID: req-304eff95-1328-40de-acee-7cdde601b62d)
```

Comment: This could be an Role Based Access Control (RBAC) issue. Are you the main Admin user on the account?

Comment: Yes, I am. I gave full access to Cloud Servers API

Comment: The reason I asked is because currently only the primary account user can delete virtual interfaces from a server. I just confirmed this by successfully deleting a public VIF as myself (the primary account holder), and then created a user from my account and was unsuccessful in deleting either the public or private VIF (resulting in the same error you're seeing). This is a known bug, as all admins should be able to delete VIFs, and it has been logged with the Dev team. Are you able to delete the VIF from the Control Panel? Not being able to would likely confirm this issue.

Comment: @JRP you are right! By using the primary account admin I was able to successfully make the request. Any idea when this bug will be fixed?

Comment: Glad that worked for you. There isn't a time frame for the fix, but it is being worked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presently only the primary account user can delete virtual interfaces from a server. This is a known bug, since all admins should be able to delete VIFs, and it has been logged with the Dev team.